# Change UILabel origin based on ScrollView scroll Position in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am currently making an application that uses UIScrollView. On scrollview i am showing short descriptions of items. For one item i have four to five descriptions and a doc type at the right side.As shown in image on scrolling top in need to scroll doc file to bottom till the end of particular item description.

[image]

How can I achieve this one?

Comment: You are going to have to give more information than that, what are you actually wanting to happen? That screenshot does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic steps -- you need to figure out the details based on your code.

1. In the VC with this scrollview, implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`
2. set the UIScrollView.delegate to the VC (e.g. in viewDidLoad) -- something like `self.scrollView.delegate = self;` (assuming your IBOutlet to the scrollview is called `scrollView`
3. In the VC add this code (fill in actual code to do what comments say):

   ```
   -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      // scrollView.contentOffset is the scroll position of the scroll view
      // Look at that and where your label sections are
      // set the AgendaLabel.center or AgendaLabel.frame appropriately
   }
   ```